# Get NamespacePrefix for a given Package Id (in org with LMA app)

Tags: apex, managed-package, tooling-api, namespace, lma

Is there a way to get the Namespace Prefix of Managed Package where I just have the Id of? Maybe it is helpful that my code sits in the same org as the [LMA](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/apex/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZynEAE) app in with its `sfLma__Package__c` objects.

- Something like `SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM PackageLicense WHERE ...`?
- Or something using **Tooling**, **Metadata** or **SOAP API**?

Example code would be helpful.

Comment: For first generation packages, you may be stuck with adding and populating your own custom field on the `sfLma__Package__c ` object.

Comment: No way to populate such a custom field via Code?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Tooling API to query `SubscriberPackage`, e.g.

```
$ force query -t "SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM SubscriberPackage WHERE Id = '033f40000001ZCXAA2'"
 NamespacePrefix
-----------------
 osfb
 (1 records)
```

Or if you have the Id of the version of the package, you can query `InstalledSubscriberPackage`, e.g.

```
$ force query -t "SELECT SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage WHERE Id = '0A3540000004uhzCAA'"
 SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix
-----------------------------------
 osfb
 (1 records)
```

Comment: But can I do this in Apex?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it from Apex (without a callout to the API).

Comment: A callout would be ok

Comment: Maybe use @afawcett's library: https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi

Comment: But it’s not a package installed in that org.

Comment: You can query SubscriberPackage by Id in any org; package ids are globally unique.  You can only query InstalledSubscriberPackage for packages installed in the org.

Answer (score 1):

Doing via Apex and the RESTAPI is pretty simple. The setup like getting the tooling endpoint and session Id varies depending on your exact implementation. The below assumes you know how to get them and uses a token to represent them:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + {$SESSIOIN_ID});

String toolingURL = '{!$TOOLING_ENDPOINT}/query/?q=SELECT+SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix+From+InstalledSubscriberPackage+WHERE+ID+=\'{$PACKAGEID}\'';

req.setEndpoint(toolingURL);
```

Then you send it. The response is the typical JSON that would deserialize as below. You will have to adjust to add the cross object field that is returned and add it to the records class below

```
public class restQueryResults {
    public Integer totalSize;
    public records[] records { get; set; }
}

public class records {
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public Boolean success;
}
```

Is that what you need to get you started?

Comment: Just to add to this: since [Winter'19](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_streamline_api_calls.htm?edition=&impact=) to define the Tooling endpoint in apex you can use `System.Url.getOrgDomainUrl()`.